# How to disable to type in HTML input date when choosing past dates?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date

I am trying to disable past dates in `input type="date"`. I can able to restrict previous dates in date picker. But when I type any previous dates in HTML date picker, I can save data even the date is already done (For example, I type *12/08/2020*)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //DISABLED PAST DATES IN APPOINTMENT DATE
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var month = dateToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dateToday.getDate();
  var year = dateToday.getFullYear();

  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();

  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

  $('#txt-appoint_date').attr('min', maxDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="txt-appoint_date" />
```

Comment: When you want to validate input's value? when form has submitted or when input looses focus or while user is typing value, ...?

Comment: When form has submitted. Because I want to save date value from database.

Comment: Just put it in a form tag, it automatically wil validate that datePicker`s value is bigger than min attribute or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `keyboard onkeydown event`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //DISABLED PAST DATES IN APPOINTMENT DATE
  var dateToday = new Date();
  var month = dateToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dateToday.getDate();
  var year = dateToday.getFullYear();

  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();

  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

  $('#txt-appoint_date').attr('min', maxDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="txt-appoint_date" onkeydown="return false"/>
```